# SetTranslation not performed in onResume/onStart methods after onPause

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, position, imagebutton

So I have a field of ImageButtons defined in XML whose positions are translated as follows:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    imageButton1.setTranslationX(10);
    //etc etc
```

This works fine and moves each member within the field as desired.  However, after cycling through lifecycle methods

> onPause onStop onDestroy onCreate onStart onResume

setTranslationX(int x) seems to fail to work and all ImageButtons return to their locations as defined in XML.  I have tried placing it directly in these lifecycle methods, or calling it from them, or from onWindowFocusChanged again, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any advice??